# How does Kindle know my login at first boot?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

I have just received my Kindle Paperwhite, which I ordered through my Amazon account (it was not a gift).

I've connected the usb cable, it started up. Connected to my wireless, and then I am presented with a screen saying "Hello <my_name>"! I was pretty amazed (and a bit creeped out at the same time)

Do any of you know how this auto-logged in to my account? Is it factory set to the buyers account? I guess this could not happen for gifts. Did it found that out by my wireless AP somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the manual, it tells you that if you purchased the device through Amazon then they use your Amazon account information and register the product to you before they ship the device.  Definitely not mining your wireless AP :)

> **Registering your Kindle**
>   If you bought your Kindle online using your Amazon account, it is already registered to you.
>   To verify, tap the Home button and look for your Amazon user name in the upper left corner
>   of the Home screen. If it says My Kindle or shows the name of a previous owner instead of
>   your own Amazon account name, you'll need to register it. See Setting up your Kindle
>   Paperwhite in this chapter for instructions on setting up and registering your Kindle.

Here is a link to the userguide:
http://kindle.s3.amazonaws.com/UserGuide/Paperwhite_V2/Kindle_Paperwhite_V2_UserGuide_US.pdf
:)

Comment: thank you! I hope they dont do that when you send it as a gift :D

Comment: They don't do that when you select "This is a gift". When you start such kindle for first time, it asks you to create an account or login into an account. Once you login, the device is registered with that account.